# What kind of task scheduling method does Android use?

Tags: android, operating-system

I am doing a study on the Android OS.

Does Android use Round Robin or Earliest Deadline First or another method?

How does the OS handle multitasking?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Android is based on Linux, it will probably use the "[Completely Fair Scheduler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completely_Fair_Scheduler)" which is the Linux default since 2007.

See also

- http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sched.7.html
- https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/scheduler/sched-design-CFS.txt